# Infinite Embedded Lists

Tags: python

input: list of [integers, lists of integers, lists of lists of integers ad infinitum]
output: list of [integers]

heres my initial solution:

```
x = [[1, 2], 1, [1], [2, 1, [1, 2]]]
numb = []
for l in x:
  if type(l) is int:
    numb.append(l)
else:
    for l2 in l:
        if type(l2) is int:
            numb.append(l2)
        else:
            for l3 in l2:
                numb.append(l3)
print(numb)
```

however this solution is only good up to three embedded lists...

i wonder if there is a way of dealing with possibly infinite embedded lists....

i.e. is there a way of coding this solution without n nested for loops for n embedded lists

Comment: Yes. Write a recursive function.

Comment: @cdhowie just to be clear, a recursive function isn't *required*. While it is usually more natural in this case, you could write a pretty straight-forward stack-based while-loop implementation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I didn't say it was required. OP asked for "a way." I gave them a way.

Comment: @cdhowie right, just to be clear.